# Finding if a value does not exist in SQL

Tags: sql

My data is structured with 5 columns (let's call them `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`) and 1,000,000+ rows. Each value in `b` has the potential for ~50 possibilities in `e` - so there could be up to 50 lines for each unique `b` value. Every `b` should have a `'-27'` among their `e` values. I would like to query all UNIQUE `b` where it doesn't have the -27 `e` value, ignoring all other possibilities for `e`.

Code so far:

```
select a, b, c, d, e
from TestDB
where not exists (select count(distinct b) from TestDB where e = '-27')
```

Would this code be sufficient? In initial tests I've done it appears to be either a) working or b) returning nothing. I'm new to SQL so I appreciate any help or being pointed in the right direction!

**edited to make it clearer I was looking for unique `'b'` values.

Comment: The count() will always return a value, 0 or larger. I.e. the NOT EXISTS will never be true.

Comment: `a`, `c`, and `d` are tied to `b` so they are only relevant in that I want them in the output. I am only concerned if a `b` does not have an `e` with a value of  `-27`. If `b` has other `e` values I don't want to know those. The purpose of this is to audit that every unique `b` value has at minimum an `e` value with `-27`. Does that help?

Comment: @Austin I have 1,000+ unique `b` values where each `b` can have ~50 different `e` values. In your example yes, that would satisfy my condition. For further clarification (hopefully!), if I had two `b = 50` and e is `0` and the other is `100` I would just need to know the `b` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to query all b where it doesn't have the -27 e value, ignoring all other possibilities for e.

If you just want the `b` values, then aggregation should work:

```
select b
from testdb t
group by b
having sum(case when e = '-27' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a correlated subquery with `NOT EXISTS`, i.e. a reference to the main query table.

```
select a, b, c, d, e
from TestDB t1
where not exists (select 1 from TestDB t2 where t2.e = '-27' and t1.b = t2.b)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
select b from TestDB where e = '-27'
```

returns all the `b`s that you want filtered out.
Use it with the operator NOT IN:

```
select a, b, c, d, e
from TestDB
where b not in (select b from TestDB where e = '-27')
```

Comment: This appears to work, would it be possible to further refine this list to unique `b` though? I realize the original question didn't specify this so that's my fault. Your code results in lines for all the `e` values for the "`b`s with no `e = '-27'`" group.

Comment: If you *realized* that your requirement is different you should post a new question and not change the requirement because this invalidates all the answers you got that provided a solution to your requirement as you posted it.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer I was looking for unique `'b'` values and have made a few clarifying comments to those who asked. I've also marked the solution accordingly. I didn't think that warranted asking a new question. Thanks for your help regardless.

Comment: *I would like to query all b where...* you added the word "unique" just now. Your code: `select a, b, c, d, e` (all columns, not just b).

Comment: Alright I don't know what else I can do but my issue has been resolved so I'm moving on.